# How to implement 2 user table for Laravel 5.1 Auth

Tags: php, laravel

I have an existing authentication in my page and n=now what I want is to implement another authentication for my admin page.

I use this package but I got an error:

```
https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth
```

Here's what I did.

1. I follow all the steps given in the package tutorial except the password resets.
2. I created a model and a migration for Admin. The column from my admin is the same as the users table but without lastname, firstname and birthday
3. Now when I try to login using this URL:
   http://localhost:8000/auth/login
   It says that the authentication details I provide don't matched in the records. I think that instead of using the `users` table for login it use the `admin` table for login which I don't have any records.
4. When I try to register using this URL: http://localhost:8000/auth/register. I don't have any error in saving but after login it redirect to the registration URL.
   Here's what my error in this page:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement
>   interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, none given

Can you provide me a step by step instruction in using the package I found? Or can you help me find out what part I missed.

Ok here's some of my codes:

**User model**

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'lastname', 'firstname', 'contact',  'email', 'birthday', 'status', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

**AuthController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $username = 'username'; //choose username instead of email
    protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard'; //if successful login
    protected $loginPath = 'auth/login'; //if not login
    protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'auth/login'; //redirect after login

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username'  => 'required|min:8|max:16|unique:users',
            'lastname'  => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'contact'   => 'required',
            'birthday'  => 'date_format: Y-m-d',
            'email'     => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password'  => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        //dd($data);

        return User::create([
            'username'  =>  $data['username'],
            'lastname'  =>  $data['lastname'],
            'firstname' =>  $data['firstname'],
            'birthday'  =>  $data['birthday'],
            'contact'   =>  $data['contact'],
            'email'     =>  $data['email'],
            'status'    =>  1,
            'password'  =>  bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

    }
}
```

**Admins migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('contact');
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('admins');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

//login user authenication
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

//registration user
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::get('dashboard', array(
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'
));
```

**login.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')
@section('header_title', 'Flax User Login')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h3><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Account Login</h3>
        <div id="login-form">
            <div class="well">
                {!! Form::open(array('routes' => 'auth/login')) !!}

                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('username')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('username', 'Username', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('username', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your Username')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('username'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('password')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your Password')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('password'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember Me</label>
                        <a href="{{ url('account/revovery') }}" class="pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-key"></span> Login</button>
                        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                        <a href="{{ url('auth/register') }}">Create New Account</a>
                    </div>

                {!! Form::close() !!}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@endsection
```

**register.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')
@section('header_title', 'Flax User Login')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h3><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Account Registration</h3>
        <div id="login-form">
            <div class="well">
                {!! Form::open(array('routes' => 'auth/register')) !!}

                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('username')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('username', 'Username', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('username', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your Username')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('username'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('lastname')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('lastname', 'Last Name', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('lastname', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your Last Name')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('lastname'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('lastname') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('firstname')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('firstname', 'First Name', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('firstname', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your First Name')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('firstname'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('firstname') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('email')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Address', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your Email Address')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('email'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('email')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('contact', 'Contact Number', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('contact', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your Contact Number')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('contact'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('contact') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('birthday')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('birthday', 'Birthday', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('birthday', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your Birthday')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('birthday'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('birthday') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('password')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Your Password')) !!}
                        @if($errors->has('password'))
                            <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Password Confirmation', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
                        {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Retype Password')) !!}
                    </div>

                    <p>Please review the information before saving it.</p>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-key"></span> Create Account</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="{{ url('auth/login') }}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Back to Login</a>
                    </div>

                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@endsection
```

Comment: Step by step instructions are available on the github page for Kbwebs/MultiAuth. Share your code, your config, the code you are using to authenticate users and admin and someone can help you get to the bottom of your problems. The error you are getting suggests your eloquent model for User or Admin does not implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface.

Comment: Ok sorry, I included some of my codes. If you need other code just tell me. :)

Comment: I would not create two different tables. Better use the normal user table and add a role column. Then you can check if the user is an admin or not.